# Network load balancing using Kubernetes container native load balancing and GCP Standalone NEG

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

**Scenario**

Use a kubernetes managed NEG ([Standalone NEG](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/standalone-neg)), as a backend for a TCP/SSL global proxy. My backend service is not a HTTP based service. Today I have set this up using network endpoint groups that targets GCE endpoints. So my want is to switch out my GCE endpoints and replace them with GKE workload.

**Problem**

Health checks for my endpoints does not work. Since my target is not http based I need to use a separate service to satisfy the HTTP based health check used by the GCP load balancer.

To demonstrate this I have used iperf as the service and a side car running the http health-checker application.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: iperf
  labels:
    app: iperf
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: iperf
  serviceName: iperf
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: iperf
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: iperf
        image: networkstatic/iperf3
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        args:
          - "-s"
        ports:
          - name: iperf
            containerPort: 5201
            protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: iperf
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
        livenessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: iperf
          initialDelaySeconds: 15
          periodSeconds: 20

      # Health checker side car
      - name: checker
        # This is the image built from the Dockerfile
        image: health-checker
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        command: ["/home/checker/health-checker/health-checker"]
        args: ["--listener=0.0.0.0:8081", "--port=5201", "--log-level=warning"]
        ports:
          - name: checker
            containerPort: 8081
            protocol: TCP

# Service with standalone neg
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: iperf-s-iperf
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"exposed_ports": {"5201":{}}}'
spec:
  selector:
    app: iperf
  ports:
  - name: iperf
    protocol: TCP
    port: 5201
    targetPort: 5201
  - name: checker
    protocol: TCP
    port: 8081
    targetPort: 8081
```

The side car container is using an image built from bellow Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

# Create home directory for the user
RUN mkdir -p /home/checker/health-checker/ && \
    useradd -m -u 1001 -U -s /bin/sh -d /home/checker checker && \
    chown -R checker:checker /home/checker/health-checker

WORKDIR /home/checker/health-checker

# Copy health-checker from Github
ADD https://github.com/gruntwork-io/health-checker/releases/download/v0.0.5/health-checker_linux_386 /home/checker/health-checker/health-checker
RUN chmod +x /home/checker/health-checker/health-checker

# Change user to checker
USER checker

CMD ["/home/checker/health-checker/health-checker"]
```

Build the image, setup the statefulset and service.

**GCP Proxy**

Next we have to setup the TCP proxy, im using a standard external TCP Load Balancer, spanned over multiple regions. The `iperf` port is the named port and protocol is TCP. For the HTTP health check I have made a standard check targeting port 8081 checking the path `/`.

Im adding the NEGs exposing the iperf port as backends to the load balancer. The target / targets are never discovered as healty.

**Expected behavior**

I expect my pods to be discovered as healthy and that the iperf port is accessible.

**Strange behavior / workaround**

Im able to "trick" the health check by installing a side service using a http ingress, targeting the same ports and pod.

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: iperf-s-checker
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: iperf
  ports:
  - name: checker
    protocol: TCP
    port: 8081
    targetPort: 8081

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: iperf-i-checker
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: iperf-s-checker
    servicePort: 8081
```

The above configuration will create an external HTTP based load balancer, with backing network endpoints. The http based health check is now using serving port as the health check target.
This will as expected work well, and we can reach the health response externally. Exciting!
Now to the strange part. Now when our backing pod has been marked as health for this http based service, we will also discover that its health in the above iperf service, and now the load balancing of non HTTP traffic works.

The way that this work is obviously not the correct way.

Is there any way to solve this? Am I missing something, maybe an annotation that can be passed during the NEG creation to separate the health check port from the serving port?

Thanks

Comment: It would be good to provide your environment details, configuration and all steps you did. Also, how you would like to see final outcome.

Comment: I have added a better explanation, and example code to reproduce the problem. @PjoterS let me know if you want any additional information

Comment: As I can see, you're using "TCP/SSL global proxy", you should expect load balancing while using it. Please have a look at the documentation [SSL Proxy Load Balancing overview](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl). Please describe you use case.

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza you are correct, I want to setup a TCP/SSL global proxy and load balance requests to it over backends using Network Endpoint Groups and container native load balancing. This setup is working very well if my endpoint groups targets GCE resources, but when my targets are GKE workload it does not work. The problem must be in the health check implementation towards GKE, as I can make this work if I implement the rather strange workaround described above.

Comment: Thanks. So it actually works with your workaround, am I right? Do you use `iperf` as a test application or it's a part of your setup?

Comment: Yes, it does work with my workaround, although the solution is not ideal. Im only using `iperf` as a tool to demonstrate the issue, and to allow a user to test it.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not clear what's the issue. Also, it's not clear why do you need HTTP health check for non-HTTP load balancer when [alternative checks are available](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl/setting-up-ssl#health-checking). If you think that you found an issue you should [report](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#issue_reports) it at [Google Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) with detailed reproduction steps and configs.

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza the proxy backends does not support anything else than HTTP health checks, so I actually dont have a choice (as far as i know). I will try to report the issue and see what happens. I would think that other people must have wanted to do a similar thing.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation **Setting up SSL Proxy Load Balancing** section [Health checking](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl/setting-up-ssl#health-checking): "Health checks determine which instances can receive new connections. **You can configure a TCP, SSL**, HTTP, or HTTPS **health check** for determining the health of your instances.", "If the service running on your backend instances uses SSL, use an SSL health check." and "Unless you have an explicit reason to use a different kind of health check, use a TCP health check.".

Comment: Also at the documentation **Setting up TCP Proxy Load Balancing** you can find that you can use TCP health checks at section [Configuring the load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/tcp/setting-up-tcp) and [Creating Health Checks](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/tcp/setting-up-tcp#health-checking) like "**6**. Configure the health check: *a*. Under Health check, select Create health check. *b*. Set the health check Name to `my-tcp-health-check`. *c*. **Under Protocol, select TCP**. *d*. **Set Port** to 110."